# Beginner PL/SQL: Return row value from dynamic SQL function

Tags: oracle, plsql, functions, dynamic-sql

I have a PL/SQL function that successfully compiles:

```
01    WITH FUNCTION find_CV_errors(
02        l_table_name IN VARCHAR
03        ,l_field_name IN VARCHAR
04        ,l_domain_name IN VARCHAR
05        ) 
06        RETURN VARCHAR
07        AS
08        l_return_value VARCHAR(128);
09    BEGIN
10    
11    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
12        'SELECT 
13            LISTAGG(CAST(' || l_field_name || ' AS VARCHAR(50)),  ' ||  ''';  ''' || ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL)
14        FROM ' ||
15            l_table_name ||
16        ' LEFT JOIN 
17            (
18            SELECT CODE
19            FROM  ENG.D_CV_ENG_VW
20            WHERE DOMAIN = :bv1
21            )
22        ON ' || l_field_name || '  = code
23        WHERE ' ||
24            l_field_name || ' IS NOT NULL
25            AND code IS NULL'
26    INTO l_return_value
27    USING l_domain_name;
28    RETURN  l_return_value;               
29    END;
```

The function has a dynamic sql query that outputs a single column in a single row via LISTAGG.

I want the function to return the the dynamic sql output as it's return value. However, right now it just returns NULL, because I haven't assigned a value to the `l_return_value` variable.

How can I assign the output from the dynamic SQL query to the `l_return_value` variable?

**Update #1:**

I've added `INTO l_return_value;` to the query (`LINE 26`), but now I'm getting an error:

`ORA-06553:PLS-103: Encountered the symbol "L_FIELD_NAME" when expecting one of the following:  : = , ( @ % ;`

**Update #2:**

When I remove the semicolon from the end of `line 26`, the function returns the value of `l_field_name`, not the value from the dynamic sql query output.

**Update #3:**

In addition to the errors Balazs Papp pointed out, I had a bind variable on `line 13`, when really I should have used a concatenated variable. Since Balazs Papp's answer uses generic examples, and not a corrected version of the question, I've corrected the original question myself (`lines 07, 13, 26, 27, 28`).

Comment: There's another option here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159851/loop-through-list-of-fields-check-against-lookup-table. It's a loop, rather than a function.

Comment: And then there's the union idea: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160758/for-each-field-name-in-a-list-of-fields-get-the-unique-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single row, use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ... INTO`. A simple example:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  l_result number;
begin
  execute immediate 'select count(*) from dual' into l_result;
  dbms_output.put_line(l_result);
end;
/

1
```

For multiple rows, use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE .. BULK COLLECT INTO`, here is an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117021/bulk-collect-into-and-execute-immediate-in-oracle

```
 declare
   type x is table of t.id%type index by pls_integer;
   xx x;
  begin
   execute immediate
   'select id from t' bulk collect into xx;
   dbms_output.put_line(xx.count);
 end;
 /
```

Ok, another example, with the 12c WITH function:

```
with function f1 (p_a number) return number
as
  l_result number;
begin
  execute immediate 'select count(*) from dba_objects where object_id = :B1' 
  into l_result
  using p_a;
  return l_result;
end;
select f1(object_id) from dba_objects where object_name = 'HELP';
/

F1(OBJECT_ID)
-------------
            1
```

Comment: @Wilson You have an unnecessary semicolon (`;`) at the end of line 26.